# Curl `unable to get local issuer certificate` when using Laravel Valet

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, laravel-valet

I'm hitting an immovable wall of (what seem to be) curl certificate errors while using Laravel Valet for local development. The current exception is:

`cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

Previous exceptions have been `invalid RSA padding` and `data too large for modulus`.

All projects are https.

What I've established:

- Occurs when using the Laravel Http facade (which uses Guzzle under the hood) to communicate between 2 local APIs.
- Browser to API is fine.
- API to external URL, like `google.com`, is fine.
- The project choices don't matter. Happens between any 2 local APIs.

What I've tried:

- php@8.1
- php@8.0
- valet@latest
- valet@2.18.0
- valet@2.17.1
- Copied the valet certs to /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs
- Copied the valet certs to /etc/ssl/certs
- Completely wiped the system, erased the drive, reinstalled Monterey@12.2.1
- configuring php ini curl.cainfo with cert path
- configuring php ini openssl.cafile with cert path
- configuring php ini openssl.capath with cert path
- Rebuilt development environments from scratch

That last one is key - I've wiped the system completely and rebuild fresh and it is *still* happening.